# How to return a C struct from a D DLL?

Tags: c++, c, dll, struct, d

I have **library written in D**, which compiles to DLL with a C interface.
When I try to return a `struct`, I get `undefined reference to 'fooFunc()'`.

What's the proper way to **return a C `struct` from a D library**?

---

Here's my D DLL code:

```d
// Earlier in source code
struct FooStruct {
    int m = 0;
}

// ...

// In main()
export extern(C) FooStruct fooFunc() {
    return FooStruct();
}
```

Here's my (C++) code, which uses the compiled DLL of the above code:

```c
// Header
typedef struct {
    int m = 0;
} FooStruct;

FooStruct fooFunc();

// ...

// In main()
FooStruct foo = fooFunc();
```

Comment: You put `extern ("C")` in your D code but not in your C++ code. How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is almost nothing wrong with your code.

What you are missing is: `extern "C" FooStruct fooFunc();` in your C++ code. Like D, C++ also needs developer to mark the C functions.

Once I made this change I easily compiled and linked these two:

**foo.d:**

```
// Earlier in source code
struct FooStruct {
    int m = 0;
}

// ...

// In main()
export extern(C) FooStruct fooFunc() {
    return FooStruct();
}
```

**foo.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

// Header
typedef struct {
    int m;
} FooStruct;

extern "C" FooStruct fooFunc();

using namespace std;

int main() {
    FooStruct foo = fooFunc();
    cout << foo.m << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile & link:

```
dejan@mrak$ dmd -c foo.d -offood.o
dejan@mrak$ g++ -o foocxx.o -c foo.cpp
dejan@mrak$ gcc -o foo food.o foocxx.o -lphobos2 -lstdc++
dejan@mrak$ ./foo 
0
```

Comment: Strange, since he wrote it in his D code. This is very close to being a typo question....!

Comment: Maybe he thought C++ does not need extern "C" .

Answer (score -2):

You should define the return value type as *struct FooStruct* cause you have not *typedef* it in your code.

In C structures are allocated in the stack, you should allocate it in the heap memory and return a pointer to it to avoid memory inconsistance.

```
typedef struct mystruct {
    int varA;
    int varB;
} mystruct_t;

//...

mystruct_t *my_new_struct(void) 
{
    mystruct_t *ptr = calloc(sizeof(struct mystruct), 1);
    // check errors and do the job!
    return ptr;
}

// returned pointer must be freed when done
```

Comment: I already `typedef`ed `FooStruct` in the C header. Do I need to `Typedef` in my D code too? I don't think that will do anything.

Comment: _"You should define the return value type as struct FooStruct cause you have not typedef it in your code."_ No, this is unnecessary in C++.

Comment: _"In C structures are allocated in the stack"_ Not necessarily. Anyway, this is C++, which hasn't had structures since 1985.

Comment: "In C structures are allocated in the stack". no they are not, they are allocated where you say. And anyway returning a struct on thats on  the stack is fine, it will be copied (you are thinking of returning pointers to local structs - which is a really BAd Thing)

Comment: _"you should allocate it in the heap memory and return a pointer to it to avoid memory inconsistance"_ Complete nonsense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit c++ has structs and always has

Comment: @pm100: You are mistaken. The keyword `struct` introduces a _class_. In fact, the keyword only exists _at all_ for backward compatibility with C programs, which is made possible because C structures and C++ classes are compatible when the class is POD. That was a deliberate design choice which had to be made, in 1985 when structures were removed from the language.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know what c++ struct does, but saying structs dont exist in c++ is simply not true. A simple struct in c++ is exactly the same as a struct in c, the fact that it can do more doesnt mean that it doesnt exist, its a superset

Comment: @pm100: Right, and as an entity with a superset of functionality, it's a fundamentally _different_ entity, with a different name: "class". But, though I can keep saying "you're wrong" until I'm blue in the face, doing so holds little value if you are unwilling to accept my wisdom. :) So let's move on.